# A bilinear estimates involving critical Sobolev norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Given $q>1$, consider the critical Sobolev space $W^{n/q,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which fails to embed in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I'm wondering if we can recover some critical estimate by considering a bilinear expression and by restricting to the radial component. For example, one could ask if the estimate
$$
\|f\,\nabla f\|_{L_r^2L_{\theta}^p}\lesssim\|f\|^2_{W^{n/q,q}\,\cap\,H^1}
\label{1}\tag{*}
$$
holds true for $p<2$, where we write $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as $x=r\theta$ with $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $\theta\in S^{n-1}$.

**Is estimate \eqref{1} actually true?** Thank you for any suggestion.